# How do I transform this data set using SQL?

Tags: sql-server

How do I write SQL that will transform data set 1 into data set 2?

> Data Set 1

```
id  Name                    Home_Phone      Work_Phone      Mobile_Phone
--- ----------------------- ------------    ------------    ------------
44  Mary James              NULL            NULL            333-832-1066
44  Mary James              111-747-7048    NULL            NULL
46  James Smith             NULL            NULL            111-354-2092
46  James Smith             111-737-8936    NULL            NULL
45  Shelley Berlin          NULL            NULL            222-960-5115
45  Shelley Berlin          NULL            222-845-2422    NULL
39  Brad Saito              NULL            NULL            NULL
39  Brad Saito              Invalid         Invalid         Invalid
55  Debbie Peters           NULL            NULL            NULL
55  Debbie Peters           NULL            NULL            NULL
55  Debbie Peters           NULL            222-960-7778    NULL
```

> Data Set 2

```
id  Name                    Home_Phone      Work_Phone      Mobile_Phone
--- ----------------------- ------------    ------------    ------------
44  Mary James              111-747-7048    NULL            333-832-1066
46  James Smith             111-737-8936    NULL            111-354-2092
45  Shelley Berlin          NULL            222-845-2422    222-960-5115
39  Brad Saito              Invalid         Invalid         Invalid
55  Debbie Peters           NULL            222-960-7778    NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you want to use some aggregation. This assumes you have only 1 row with a value for each id, Name combination.

```
select id
    , Name
    , HousePhone = MAX(Home_Phone)
    , WorkPhone = MAX(Work_Phone)
    , MobilePhone = MAX(Mobile_Phone)
from YourTable
group by id
    , Name
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just needed to be reminded how to do collapse my results using MAX().

Answer (score -1):

Use an UPDATE statement if you are wanting to take the data from one dataset to the other.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer. Try answering clearer questions until your rep is high enough to comment.